# Extend a generic partial class

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

my question could seem strange.

I use a class to encapsulate a method to not have to build a class of the interface (it's a bit long to explain and i don't want to go too far).

I would to know if it was possible to "extend" a generic class  by add partial to "extend" its generic part. The purpose is to keep the same name class, but by add one (or more in the future) generic type to have the possibility to encapsulate any method, then pass the object  containing the function and that include this interface.

I need to have:

```
    new Foo<string>()
    new Foo<string, int>()
    ...
```

I 'successful' made this i think, but perhaps it will generate some bug i can't imagine right now, or perhaps it's not.. how to say a good way to program.

Example:

- Original

```
    // A class to encapsulate a method "without parameter"
    partial Foo<T>: Interface
    {
        public Func<Interface, T> FooLambda{ get; set; }
      
        public virtual object Run()
        {
            return ToRun(this);
        }
    }
```

The method i need to pass (from another class)

```cs
        void FooToEncapsulate(Interface patt)
        {
            //--- My code using an object with the interface pattern
        }
```

---

- Add another generic Type to Foo

The part to "extend" Foo

```cs
    partial Foo<T,Y>: Foo<Y>
    {
        public new Func<Interface, T, Y> FooLambda{ get; set; }
      
        public T Param {get;set;}  

        public override object Run()
        {
            return this.ToRun(this, Param);  
        }
    }
```

The **other** method i need to pass (from another class)

```
        void FooToEncaspulate(Interface patt, int param)
        {
            //--- My code using an object with the interface pattern
            //--- and "param"
    
        }
```

I have no problem for the while with this code, and i know it's something that could be strange, must i forget to use this technic, or could i think it was thought to work also like this ? Must i think if it compiles that means it's ok ? Is there another way to proceed like this without create a new class, and extend in same time on the generic part ?

(Sorry for my english)

Thx.

---

---

Edit:

I thought by using partial that could be a good idea, because i would to keep the same name for my class. After have read an answer and comment from Enigmativity, i **tried without partial**, and i have no errors relating to the name of the class when i compile.

If i well understand, the fact to add generic parameter to a class makes that create as many class than as "variants" depending on the generic type. "Partial" is useful to split code on several files on a basic class.

Is partial could be useful on code split with the same number of generic type ?

Comment: `extend a generic class by add partial` no, that's not what `partial` does. It doesn't extend anything. It's just a file management feature. Your code contains *two different classes* that aren't affected by `partial` at all

Comment: It is possible to split the definition of a class, a struct, an interface or a method over two or more source files. Each source file contains a section of the type or method definition, and all parts are combined when the application is compiled.

Comment: That's what I wrote. `partial` has nothing to do with inheritance or generics and doesn't affect them

Comment: @Vonkel. - Your code is quite flaky - I assume instead of `ToRun` you meant you want `FooLambda` there? But then your second class doesn't work because it appears you are trying to pass a second parameter to `ToRun`. You also called this parameter `Param`, but the only variable you show is `timeSleep`. Can you please clean this all up so that the code is as close to real as possible? Then we can give you a clear answer.

Comment: Sorry Enigmativity you are right, i would to clean the most possible to give a clear example and i forget to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the word `partial` to extend a class with a single generic type to have two generic types. They are in fact two distinct classed.

This works fine:

```
class Foo<T>
{

}

class Foo<T, Y> : Foo<Y>
{

}
```

Now, as said in the comments, the rest of your code is quite flaky. If you can clean up the code I could provide you with a more answer that will be of more use to you.

Comment: I think it's ok now, i removed 'timesleep', added 'Param', add Y parameter to FooLambda. Sorry but it was late for me, i missed a lot of things when i wrote. If you want my purpose is too 

 There is something i can't understand, and i appreciate the way you answered me, when you say that there will be two different class you mean because i add a generic type ? For this precise case ? If it is i understand and even i understand also why partial could be useless here in this case.

Comment: @Vonkel. - A class is unique given its name and the number of generic parameters it has. `Foo<T>` and `Foo<T, Y>` are unique types. The same with `Foo` (it has zero generic parameters).

Comment: Thx, it's a situation i never met before. After your answer i thought about the methods that can use different parameters and keep the same name, and understood it must be something near that.